# how to send an object data that contains hashset of another object from jsp to controller in spring mvc;

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

This is my jsp code 
stuff contains list of stuffPacking

```
        var stuffPackingData;
        var kindOfStuffData;
        var array = [];
        var grid = $j("#kindOfStuffGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var stuffPackingTempDS = stuffPackingDS.view();
        for (var i = 0; i < grid._data.length; i++) {
            var kindId = findKindOfStuffUnitIdByName(grid._data[i].kindOfStuffUnitName);
            kindOfStuffData = {
                'id': kindId,
                'name': grid._data[i].kindOfStuffUnitName
            }
            stuffPackingData = {
                'number': grid._data[i].number,
                'kindOfStuffUnit': kindOfStuffData,
            }
            array.push(stuffPackingData);
        }

        kindOfStuffData = {
            'id': $('#kindOfStuffUnitName').val(),
        }
        var data = {
            'id': lastSelectedStuffFullId,
            'name': $('#stuffNameInsertInput').val(),
            'kindOfStuffUnit': kindOfStuffData,
            'barcode': $('#stuffBarCodeInsert').val(),
            'irancode': $('#stuffIranCodeInsert').val(),
            'weight': $('#StuffWeightInsert').val(),
            'priceBuy': removeComma($("#stuffBuyPriceInsert").val()),
            'priceSell': removeComma($("#stuffSellPriceInsert").val()),
            'minimumStock': $("#stuffMinStockInsert").val(),
            'orderPoint': $("#stuffOrderPointInsert").val(),
            'percentAvarez': $("#stuffAvarezPercentInsert").val(),
            'percenrTax': $("#stuffTaxPercentInsert").val(),
            'stuffPackings': array,
            'year': "1395"
        };
        $.ajax({           
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: contexPath + stuffUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
```

and in controller im trying to add a new stuff that contains hashset of stuffPackings

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/Add")
public @ResponseBody
String Add(@Valid @RequestBody Stuff stuff, BindingResult result) {
```

in controller i cant access to my stuffpacking data

is ther another way to send and save this kind of values without these trubels?

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp code is right,
You can do this by below code
just change your controller like this

```
HashSet<StuffPacking> SP = new HashSet<StuffPacking>();
        Object[] objArray = stuff.getStuffPackings().toArray();
        for (Object temp : objArray) {
            LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap(5);
            map = (LinkedHashMap) temp;

            StuffPacking stuffPacking = new StuffPacking();
            stuffPacking.setNumber(Double.valueOf(map.get("number").toString()));
            LinkedHashMap unitId= (LinkedHashMap)(map.get("kindOfStuffUnit"));

            KindOfStuffUnit kindunit = new KindOfStuffUnit();
            kindunit.setId(Byte.valueOf(unitId.get("id").toString()));
            stuffPacking.setKindOfStuffUnit(kindunit);
            stuffPacking.setStuff(stuff);
            SP.add(stuffPacking);
        }

        stuff.setStuffPackings(SP);
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh my god that was great.that actually worked.are you one of Dr.Ziglari's employee?